# Vue.js import child component into a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, eslint, vue-cli

Today I am making an todo web app, but now I want to import a `Todo` in my `Todolist` component.  My components:

App (Parent) --> Todolist (Child) --> Todo (Child)

**Error:**

> 24:5  error  The "Todo" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components

**Code**

*Todolist*

```
<template>
<!-- TEMPLATE FOR THE TODOS -->

  <div v-for="(todo) in todos" :key="todo.id">
    <Todo
      :todo="todo.text"
      :index="todo.id"
      :checked="todo.checked"
      :deleteTodo="deleteTodo"
    />
  </div>

</template>
```

```js
<script>
import Todo from './Todo'

export default {
  name: 'Todolist',
  props: {
    todos: Array
  }
}
</script>
```

The command line is telling me that the import has been imported, but the import has not been used yet.

Hope you guys can help me out,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Importing the child component's export is the first step, now its available to the current module.  But you still need to register that imported component in the parent using the `components` option:

*Parent*

```
import Todo from './Todo'

export default {
  name: 'Todolist',
  props: {
    todos: Array
  },
  components: {  // ✅ add this
    Todo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import a component dynamically, registration, as described above, is still required.

Use instead:

`import Todo from './Todo'`

this option

`const Todo = () => import('./Todo')`

The component will be loaded only when needed.

**or**

You can add a component by importing and registering in `components`

```js
components: {            
            Todo: () => import('./Todo'),
        },
```